# CakePHPが500エラーで起動できない

Tags: php, cakephp

CakePHPが起動せず困っております。

エラーログには以下の通り記録されています。

```
[22-Oct-2019 07:39:11 Asia/Tokyo] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Cake\Http\Server' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mycakeapp/webroot/index.php:37
Stack trace:
 #0 {main}<br>thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mycakeapp/webroot/index.php on line 37
```

`webroot/index.php`の37行目は以下のようになっております。

```
// Bind your application to the server.
$server = new Server(new Application(dirname(__DIR__) . '/config'));
```

何度調べてもわからず、途方に暮れております。
どなたかご教授頂けないでしょうか。

Comment: CakePHPのインストール手順は、Cookbook の手順通りでしょうか？https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/ja/installation.html#cakephp

Comment: 情報が少なすぎるので、インストールしようとしたCakePHPのバージョン、 インストール時の手順と、webroot/index.php の内容を全て掲載してもらえらば問題の切り分けが少しできると思います。

Comment: マルチポスト https://teratail.com/questions/218571

Answer (score 1):

`Uncaught Error: Class 'Cake\Http\Server' not found` のエラーは `\Cake\Http\Server` の定義されているファイルが見つかりませんよということです。

現段階で考えられる原因と対策は、

- composer installに失敗している

  - /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mycakeapp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Server.php はありますか？
  - `vendor/` ディレクトリを削除した後、ターミナルで `composer install` を実行してみてください
- autoloaderが読み込まれていない

  - webroot/index.php で vendor/autoload.php は読み込んでいますか？
  - 記述を確認してターミナルで `composer dumpautoload` を実行してみてください
- webroot/index.php に `use Cake\Http\Server;` の宣言が記述されていない

  - webroot/index.phpの記述を確認してみてください

あたりになります。